# Design pattern for list of strings in class which represent a type or a message

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

The topic title is maybe not a good description for my question but i failed to find a better one.

Basicly a common problem i encountered over time was the definition of a class that contains constant variables which represent some kind of type or state.

```
<?php
class Notification {

     const TYPE_MAIL = 'mail';
     const TYPE_EXPORT = 'export';
     ...
}
```

You then store the object in a storage layer and later retrieve it again. 
Some common queries to retrieve these objects are 'where type = "mail"'.

Of course the application grows and types continue to be added.
Could someone point me to a good design pattern to handle this kind of architecture problem? I would love to see some examples of constructions that avoid this kind of static declaration.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php ?

Comment: Well I learned something new today! Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with saying where type = ".Notification::TYPE_MAIL." ?

Comment: The list can get quite huge and lacks maintainability. I haven't found a better way to do it hence the post on stack :)

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem, and I've heard the problem called using magic numbers (undefined string constants used in your code)

I found an article here: [Practial PHP refactoring - Magic numbers](https://dzone.com/articles/practical-php-refactoring-12)
*Better link: [SO - Coding Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)*

What I like to do is add all the relevant constant in the entity/model that uses them, thatway they are placed in the right context of your app.

For example, in my Customer entity/model, I have an area in the top of my class for class constant, one field in my customer table is type, and the relevant constants are `const TYPE_DEMO = 0; const TYPE_SHOP = 1; const TYPE_SOMETHINGELSE = 99;`

The results is when using them, I can say `$customerType = Customer::TYPE_SHOP;` wich is wery readable :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem i described. I just used strings instead of numbers :) I am really hoping there is a nicer solution to this than this.
Thanks for your feedback though :)